# Repeat header for each drilldown row in ssrs

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, drilldown

I need help in SSRS 2010. I have tabel with 4 columns. First and second columns are grouped and third column has drilldown. How can I repeate values of first and second column for each row of drilldown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that you don't want to do a group on the first and second column if you want the values to repeat for each row. Remove the grouping and just do a sort on the table and that should get the column values to repeat but still sort the "like" data.